# Run a file locally in java (reach with 'localhost')

Tags: java, http, get, localhost, serve

I've been requested at work to run a file (server app) locally (so I will have it in localhost) and then send http get requests as I desire.
(I'm using get requests in the form "wget ..... http://localhost:4567/XXXX"
XXXX contains the name of the item I'm trying to receive.

I'm not familiar with the term 'run a file locally'. Can anyone explain / direct me to a website that explains about it?
Suppose my server file name is 'server'. How do I run the file (locally) in java? (so I'll be able to send HTTP get requests as I've mentioned above)

Comment: Ask the person who gave you this task what **they** meant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for running html files locally so that they can be accessed through a port? If this is the case you need to have a http server on your desktop/laptop and configure it to enable your html files. If it is complete J2EE/.Net/any other platform applications, we need to install appropriate web/application server and run the same.

Comment: No. I'm using a colleague's server file which I need to run locally. and then I have to use http get requests to my localhost (in which the server file should be accessed with because I've 'ran the server file locally) and ask for specific parameters. For example, for parameter floors. I'm using "wget -q ....... http://localhost:4567/floors. the server knows what paramter I'm asking for. I'm just trying to realize how can one run a file locally (seriously have no clue).

Comment: What do you mean by server file?

Comment: Umm just a file (compiled - exe file) which is able to receive requests (which have been given beforehand) and answer them. The server is not important - just an exe file.

Comment: If it is exe, then you just need to double click so that it will start running. Or you can open command prompt and then type that exe name. Not sure whether you are looking for this answer or expecting some thing else

Comment: Trying to figure out if I can run the file using java. Is exec the solution? I want the file to be always available for receivng http get requests.

Comment: If file is exe, you don't require to run through java. If it is jar or war only you have run through java

Answer (score 0):

You have to create webservices and define its path. Suppose if you create a method give it a `@Path('someName')`. Define what it should consume and what it should produce using `@Consumes(MEDIA_TYPE.xxx) @Produces(MEDIA_TYPE.xxx)`. The whole project will have a base path like `restApi`. Run it using apache tomcat i desired port. Access the rest api with the url `http://localhost:8080/restApi/someName`. Refer java webservices for more details. Its very simple. Starting configuration may take some time. So start with a maven artifact for java webservises to have a head start.

Comment: Thanks Max, I'm really new to this area (got the work out of no where). Do you know if there's a way to run a server file locally in java? or the file should be run with some other program (for example the apache tomcat you've suggested), and only after that I'll be able to access the file with http getrequest to my localhost?

Comment: Yes you have to add your local project to tomcat. Then only it'll be accessible from tomcat. Just check this [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-annotations-example) for creating the project. You can use JAX-WS or JAX-RS(RESTful) based on your needs. After creating the project place it inside tomcat working directory  manually or configure it using your IDE(Eclipse). Then you can access it from local host.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to send some GET requests to check the responses I would use a simple REST client like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). Just enter your URL, choose the GET method and send the request.

To run something locally means that the server is installed locally. You would deploy your file/s (.war or .ear in the case of java) to this local server. After that you can access the deployed services via http://localhost:port/...